# обработка входящих данных GET

Tags: javascript, php, html, get

Друзья подскажите плз, у меня на страницу приходит значение переменной, либо 0 либо 1, в зависимости от этого значения мне нужно скрывать или показывать определенной окно. Загвоздка в том что проверять какое значение пришло я буду через php код, а вот скрывать элемент мне уже придется либо через js либо через css
и я вот не понимаю, как например сделать чтобы внутри проверки, которая написана на php был бы код на js, который скрывал или показывал бы элементы?

Answer (score 1):

```html
<div id=mydiv> определённое окно </div> 
<script>
var data = '<?php echo $data; ?>';
var mydiv = document.getElementById("mydiv");
if(data == "1") {
    mydiv.style.display = "block";
} else {
    mydiv.style.display = "none";
}
</script>
```